# Makefile for texi2pdf command

Tags: make

I use texi2pdf to generate pdf files from texinfo files using
the command

```
texi2pdf myfile.texi
```

Am working on using a makefile for this and have written

```
name=06a-amcoh

texi=${name}.texi

pdf=${name}.pdf

all: ${pdf}

${pdf}: ${texi}
    texi2pdf $<

clear:
    rm -f ${pdf}
```

I could do with some help on the correct way to write the makefile and how to run it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use a pattern rule:

```make
PDFS := 06a-amcoh.pdf

all: $(PDFS)

%.pdf: %.texi
        texi2pdf $< -o $@

clean:
        rm -f $(PDFS)
```

This will work for any PDF you want to generate from a Texinfo file.

To run this:

```
make
```

will do (the first target is the default).

Comment: Thank you so very much.  I have many directories with texi files.  Does one usually have a makefile in each directory?

Comment: There’s no general rule, it really depends on how you manage your project (or collections of files).

Comment: Would also like to have a rule for making html files with "texi2any -c HTML_MATH=mathjax --html myfile.texi"